# Почему не встаёт картинка на задний фон?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

В css в секцию .promo установила картинку для заднего фона, но она не отображается на странице. Почему?

```css
html {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #212121;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 13px 70px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu .menu_link {
    color: #ffffff;
    /* font-family: 'Roboto'; */
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.menu .menu_item {
    border-right: 2px dotted black;
    padding-right: 28px;
}

.subheader {
    height: 84px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.subheader .subheader_logo  {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.subheader .subheader_official {
    margin-top: 6px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #ffffff;
    /* font-family: "Roboto"; */
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.subheader .subheader_call {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 19px;
    text-align: right;
}

.subheader .subheader_phone {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 12px;
}

.subheader .subheader_btn {
    margin-top: 19px;
    width: 172px;
    height: 46px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7 0%, #4ce2ff 100%);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.promo {
    min-height: 800px;
    background: url('../img/bg/car_bg.png') center center/over no-repeat; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Со своим автомобилем</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">На автомобиле компании<a><li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Требования</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Контакты</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Оставить заявку</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="subheader">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                        <a href="#" class="subheader_logo"><img src="icons/icons_logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                        <div class="subheader_official">Официальный партнер Uber в Москве</div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2">
                        <div class="subheader_call">Звоните нам ежедневно</div>
                        <a href="tel:+74957970988" class="subheader_phone">8 495 797 09 88</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button class="subheader_btn">заказать звонок</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="promo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                    <h1 class="promo_header">КОМПАНИЯ UBER PARTNERS!</h1>
                    <h2 class="promo_subheader">ПРИГЛАШАЕМ ВОДИТЕЛЕЙ! НА СВОЕМ АВТО!</h2>
                    <div class="provo_descr">Компания UBER  динамически развивающаяся. Компания на рынке занимает лидирующее место среди
                        таксомоторных компаний, Компания абсолютно прозрачная вы можете контролировать все процессы у себя в личном кабинете. Бонуcная система.Помимо выполненной работы по заказам, компания начисляет бонусы за
                        пиковое время.
                        <br><br>
                        Мы одни из партнеров и зарекомендовали себя как одна из лучших команд в городе Москве.  Водители у нас
                        зарабатывают от 80000- 120000 в месяц.
                    </div>
                    <button class="promo_btn">ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

(последние строки в коде)

Comment: Файл `car_bg.png` находится не там, где Вы думаете.

Comment: а где он находится?

Comment: я всё проверила, он находится именно в той папке, в которую я указала путь

Comment: Что есть "center/over"?

Comment: Не встречал такую вещь center/over, после того как ее убрать - все отбражается.

Answer (score 0):

background: url('../img/bg/car_bg.png') center, center/over, no-repeat;
здесь нужно после запятой